Finding particular solution for DE
I need to find a particular solution for the following DE
\begin{equation*}
y^{\prime \prime \prime}-2 y^{\prime \prime}+y^{\prime}-2 y=\mathrm{e}^{-x}\left[\left(9-5 x+4 x^2\right) \cos 2 x-\left(6-5 x-3 x^2\right) \sin 2 x\right] .
\end{equation*} I found $y_p = e^{-x} \left[ (A + Bx + Cx^2) \cos 2x + (D + Ex + Fx^2) \sin 2x \right]
$ But I am not sure whether I should take the third and second derivatives of this and then solve it to find the coefficients. Because it is too long, is there an algebraic trick that I am missing? I appreciate any help you can provide.

@Moo It asks for the particular solution of the given equation.

If you don't mind working with complex-valued coefficients, you can condense the right side by converting from trig to exponential,$$(\cos x,\sin x)=\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2,\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)$$At the very least it'll be easier on the eyes. Another thing you can do is to solve each sub-ODE obtained by splitting up the non-homogeneous part and applying the principle of superposition, which says the solutions to $f(y,y',y'',\ldots)=f(x)$ and $f(y,y',y'',\ldots)=g(x)$ can be combined to solve $f(y,y',y'',\ldots)=f(x)+g(x)$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27%27-2+y%27%27%2By%27-2+y%3De%5E%7B-x%7D+%5B+%289-5+x%2B4+x%5E2%29+%5Ccos%282+x%29-+%286-5+x-3+x%5E2%29+%5Csin%28+2+x%29+%5D+

an useful trick: put $z=y \exp(x)$
